# Count if item next to field contains certain text

Tags: excel

I'd like to run a function that can find how many of a certain value are next to a specified value. For instance for B2:B90 in the field is 'eyes' how many '$10' amounts are in those rows?

```
    $10             eyes     
    not today      off      
    $5          eyes     
    not today      off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,10,B:B,"eyes")
```